# update record where employee_id = $id && last inserted id mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

i am implementing a CMS so i have a one problem 
How to Update the last insert record in mysqli
here is my php code

```
<?php

include 'dbconfig.php';
include 'session.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];
//echo $id; die;  
if (isset($_POST['logIn'])) {

    $timezone = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimezone($timezone);
    $time = $date->format(' H:i:s');

    $query = "INSERT INTO logindata (empId, logIn) VALUES ( '$id', '$time') "; // 
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $query);


    if ($result) {
        header("Location: https://google.com");
    }
} elseif (isset($_POST['logOut'])) {
    $timezone1 = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
    $date1 = new DateTime();
    $date1->setTimezone($timezone1);
    $time1 = $date1->format(' H:i:s');
// update record from here    
    $sql = "UPDATE logindata SET logOut='$time1' WHERE login_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() && empId = '$id'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql);

    if ($result1) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                  window.location = "http://facebook.com"
    </script>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `last_insert_id()` only keeps track of PER-CONNECTION inserts. your update is done in a completely different code path than the insert, therefore the update code path will never have a "previous" insert to call last_insert_id() on. insert IDs are only kept on a per-connection basis, and your update will take place in a DIFFERENT connection than the insert.

Comment: so what i do Marc B

Comment: why do you need to track records this way? if everything was working perfectly, there should be only ONE record for that user with a null/blank logout time. and note that you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)